# how do I set an Image which is Received in a Json Object thorough a web service as a response below...?

Tags: android, json, imageview, http-post, arrays

how do i decode this to show in an ImageView...? in Android

```
"IMGFILE1":[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,255,254,0,42,73,110,116,101,108,40,82,41,32,74,80,69,71,32,76,105,98,114,97,114,121,44,32,118,101,114,115,105,111,110,32,49,44,53,44,52,44,51,54,0,255,219,0,67,0,6,4,5,6,5,4,6,6,5,6,7,7,6,8,10,16,10,10,9,9,10,20,14,15,12,16,23,20,24,24,23,20,22,22,26,29,37,31,26,27,35,28,22,22,32,44,32,35,38,39,41,42,41,25,31,45,48,45,40,48,37,40,41,40,255,219,0,67,1,7,7,7,10,8,10,19,10,10,19,40,26,22,26,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,255,192,0,17,8,1,64,0,240,3,1,34,0,2,17,1,3,17,1,255,196,0,27,0,0,2,3,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,4,1,2,5,0,6,7,255,196,0,60,16,0,2,1,2,4,1,9,6,5,3,4,3,1,0,0,0,1,2,0,3,17,4,18,33,49,65,5,19,34,81,97,113,129,145,177,6,35,50,161,193,240,51,146,210,225,226,20,66,114,82,98,209,241,22,52,67,36,255,196,0,20,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,196,0,20,17,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,218,0,12,3,1,0,2,17,3,17,0,63,0,46,107,78,61,53,180,236,183,150,248,4,0,21,200,109,215,172,29,70,18,216,135,187,2,34,192,150,227,2,174,65,184,149,91,134,22,156,224,134,222,51,70,144,98,47,0,171,170,11,245,8,53,68,190,208,245,151,37,61,34,201,80,102,218,5,170,34,220,105,8,17,114,13,36,102,82,195,72,70,101,202,44,32,47,204,41,107,218,21,114,168,177,18,212,106,41,221,126,82,106,148,177,211,229,0,99,45,246,151,32,17,180,161,176,23,2,64,168,111,194,4,84,178,176,180,130,196,129,164,165,90,132,17,112,36,115,194,195,79,148,3,4,4,94,210,140,114,240,146,181,236,182,183,202,81,170,3,195,229,2,3,22,107,90,25,16,24,1,80,3,160,249,72,74,196,184,2,3,130,157,182,156,137,106,163,186,90,153,184,23,151,65,122,158,16,22,196,31,123,0,79,188,240,140,227,22,213,98,76,79,61,225,3,74,154,146,179,154,157,129,60,97,40,176,201,180,163,181,201,234,128,177,27,197,154,193,163,150,189,226,117,80,230,223,137,129,44,192,211,51,176,172,46,101,114,30,109,181,130,161,112,231,88,27,192,5,222,41,139,172,115,89,72,2,51,92,233,51,171,252,119,129,45,240,2,119,50,148,1,39,89,98,215,65,34,137,177,128,90,148,197,175,105,85,114,134,48,72,41,21,117,185,210,5,234,226,9,91,18,45,58,138,43,2,110,47,7,204,19,192,249,195,45,19,76,29,252,224,14,165,149,247,22,135,76,175,76,109,231,22,117,12,250,222,17,20,170,217,118,129,52,233,244,244,235,16,237,70,252,98,232,236,26,117,74,238,27,120,12,133,10,53,214,85,42,40,125,135,156,29,54,102,93,101,5,131,192,182,37,129,182,222,112,1,65,23,151,172,186,64,134,43,164,2,168,211,88,65,76,21,214,9,46,208,197,178,172,5,170,40,13,174,208,84,135,188,22,132,170,217,175,40,154,24,14,179,229,65,172,190,22,173,223,88,186,130,250,24,106,20,138,180,2,226,192,99,126,49,78,104,151,184,190,221,81,154,230,214,148,15,107,109,180,3,170,128,187,72,57,109,251,206,12,25,96,25,142,110,200,7,1,64,208,64,212,26,222,93,111,33,132,0,145,100,32,65,34,11,147,109,99,89,6,83,42,180,247,210,1,113,142,45,51,234,18,90,55,138,23,180,91,33,188,14,23,42,37,81,90,241,148,78,136,151,20,172,56,121,64,162,27,88,25,122,100,22,149,97,99,33,77,140,6,213,215,107,25,12,202,231,47,19,215,7,76,92,222,113,5,92,24,18,248,108,164,19,151,206,16,32,84,16,111,87,97,172,147,82,234,32,84,0,90,240,85,74,230,218,89,94,10,174,164,218,5,213,133,180,128,39,166,111,215,44,128,129,4,88,7,241,128,86,38,218,153,212,211,49,220,65,214,109,52,131,90,185,53,36,249,192,113,192,64,13,197,187,226,88,140,64,59,24,12,110,52,11,11,159,51,51,6,39,57,220,249,192,210,167,80,179,90,241,250,118,11,168,153,184,97,112,12,208,166,192,0,12,6,168,16,78,154,71,180,234,136,209,23,58,70,179,64,30,33,115,29,32,74,244,120,111,105,216,170,133,79,31,56,191,58,109,199,175,120,23,70,32,218,49,161,94,216,178,142,50,203,83,164,4,6,84,137,207,43,76,220,203,184,210,7,13,1,149,190,182,146,53,157,109,96,6,163,221,128,227,42,250,8,58,141,106,235,225,235,10,122,77,2,244,26,226,18,161,210,82,146,216,25,119,26,64,14,230,115,141,116,157,177,188,226,220,109,1,170,3,163,191,1,40,237,113,0,43,229,225,243,156,88,223,247,129,113,76,177,189,140,158,108,246,200,90,214,26,201,24,129,120,16,41,235,43,81,66,92,147,99,37,42,130,254,81,62,82,175,98,219,237,215,219,0,197,134,83,17,168,227,57,212,111,32,214,38,159,31,57,153,136,174,84,157,78,231,140,2,99,249,73,105,173,206,95,187,246,204,215,229,132,97,96,87,239,198,100,242,189,98,201,161,59,117,247,204,154,65,203,110,124,224,110,98,241,249,218,224,3,247,223,43,132,197,92,139,216,106,34,20,65,203,210,222,93,6,87,191,108,15,95,129,197,40,85,185,81,227,217,31,74,153,136,60,39,141,165,139,203,85,70,190,115,215,224,125,229,21,183,81,245,129,165,66,178,168,220,70,18,178,151,176,34,103,10,103,170,29,20,165,93,122,160,95,26,224,212,0,111,40,5,200,255,0,24,182,42,175,255,0,164,125,240,133,167,82,246,238,128,219,40,11,22,96,67,94,198,53,184,146,180,139,105,2,48,231,81,125,35,109,108,187,143,56,185,164,84,203,212,83,146,5,144,169,216,131,227,42,228,3,184,131,162,164,94,117,64,111,0,120,140,57,21,151,184,122,206,40,85,161,49,21,143,58,186,240,131,106,183,125,96,93,90,198,20,155,136,170,146,196,145,25,27,107,0,100,113,150,83,223,42,205,172,184,181,160,65,0,245,200,176,34,91,94,18,26,202,166,0,42,46,186,66,80,164,8,57,141,140,25,125,101,26,179,131,161,128,226,208,215,67,50,121,86,155,6,111,190,49,250,56,162,7,72,235,7,138,81,90,228,141,224,96,86,173,205,211,55,19,19,21,142,92,199,109,204,221,229,10,104,41,189,199,221,167,146,198,39,188,33,77,181,48,22,197,130,64,189,165,48,235,97,188,189,99,123,92,72,77,4,2,15,139,73,96,218,193,211,185,38,89,198,86,129,27,86,4,237,61,135,36,99,233,133,69,184,251,61,243,199,232,199,81,115,52,57,41,159,250,148,25,180,184,225,218,32,125,35,10,82,162,130,15,0,119,145,92,0,227,186,15,146,210,244,151,95,237,30,145,150,165,159,83,188,12,60,118,152,139,253,237,58,141,64,13,187,35,88,252,48,231,47,22,230,149,24,105,194,6,165,26,128,168,141,43,116,116,222,101,211,98,54,142,210,109,6,176,8,236,122,164,85,169,100,218,89,108,119,130,112,24,216,237,2,148,171,92,218,209,128,11,136,168,167,145,129,180,119,12,84,139,24,9,226,20,243,139,175,9,9,78,239,172,111,20,192,144,109,111,24,4,55,107,237,2,201,76,11,247,194,91,73,8,119,227,57,170,128,118,30,112,6,86,237,46,69,132,178,186,239,167,156,171,84,15,160,31,56,21,13,172,173,67,116,50,165,72,63,180,186,173,208,220,192,89,65,36,206,203,210,180,58,1,154,209,132,160,50,220,157,224,34,212,173,168,144,213,45,76,142,49,194,67,105,111,156,67,26,69,48,218,129,218,123,224,98,114,147,18,143,247,194,121,44,83,55,56,117,226,103,160,199,214,190,96,62,244,153,45,70,237,115,115,225,1,58,202,45,5,176,142,189,43,219,127,41,122,120,112,70,160,192,66,141,203,24,122,137,115,27,74,10,173,10,244,133,175,3,48,38,86,6,59,201,253,26,232,71,95,214,85,169,220,194,225,215,43,131,3,220,242,61,86,42,162,255,0,218,61,38,150,98,39,158,228,90,199,48,29,131,208,207,69,80,90,2,88,226,73,138,17,125,76,111,22,96,23,81,180,14,166,35,10,74,137,90,84,244,222,93,150,208,10,140,109,58,152,44,242,244,212,101,140,97,213,67,220,192,29,74,64,142,16,12,198,145,210,104,86,97,107,15,88,163,211,204,111,0,88,162,109,22,66,122,227,88,173,160,18,220,96,89,92,129,105,57,115,27,155,202,177,28,8,149,71,59,94,1,88,5,67,169,188,21,39,179,111,34,160,6,231,48,148,164,0,109,76,6,57,221,120,74,53,94,152,0,239,46,50,95,113,231,0,85,70,183,23,128,108,217,106,3,30,44,166,138,30,193,51,20,230,58,202,215,196,243,100,40,34,221,240,43,95,16,200,198,199,214,121,206,84,199,86,106,142,165,206,94,243,215,3,202,248,215,21,78,86,22,183,103,80,153,10,94,181,81,153,174,15,100,13,69,92,235,115,172,9,0,24,222,26,141,144,111,110,233,21,105,11,233,0,34,136,60,37,197,43,13,163,184,113,115,168,50,245,64,27,192,202,122,103,62,131,132,5,70,42,214,51,88,20,205,169,27,117,204,252,80,6,173,198,208,23,205,121,125,0,184,145,96,106,14,169,36,88,64,215,228,42,135,158,223,128,244,51,216,177,188,240,92,157,83,155,169,123,219,254,140,246,88,58,185,219,113,2,49,102,198,82,157,138,195,226,144,49,26,202,211,166,2,233,2,244,150,240,198,150,155,73,162,160,8,70,168,163,75,143,56,21,181,150,11,57,83,161,156,245,46,116,34,82,247,128,192,98,78,166,92,84,80,56,121,69,3,155,74,27,147,2,216,130,204,32,66,181,163,53,218,194,44,181,134,107,94,0,234,43,131,165,252,224,65,113,215,231,29,103,218,39,89,206,104,16,197,200,211,214,15,59,141,207,206,21,11,17,125,96,220,158,48,44,149,79,92,150,168,109,34,152,6,7,25,136,166,148,137,7,135,92,1,226,177,109,73,116,107,121,204,78,80,229,39,184,179,241,237,237,139,242,166,48,51,16,172,126,93,147,44,146,230,230,7,45,106,152,138,151,115,125,68,118,154,100,32,136,189,32,6,208,156,225,190,176,54,168,213,247,96,94,84,181,204,70,149,93,55,150,53,128,227,3,114,146,46,182,38,43,202,23,3,66,124,251,162,75,136,202,62,47,72,182,47,18,91,102,244,129,44,236,172,65,38,82,165,66,120,197,185,194,78,166,75,18,96,19,57,28,101,195,102,139,132,99,194,88,6,16,30,163,61,23,37,226,14,98,47,247,164,242,244,73,188,218,193,84,9,80,107,3,208,53,66,91,120,100,38,194,102,165,112,92,107,52,233,84,92,139,254,34,1,20,155,65,61,203,70,24,139,105,6,7,74,240,33,84,91,88,42,143,151,104,207,54,72,208,69,234,211,35,113,0,84,220,179,8,229,53,5,98,42,108,68,106,147,220,64,140,71,13,98,173,96,208,184,167,181,162,76,196,180,7,169,140,203,7,81,69,246,30,82,112,231,221,193,214,222,5,210,219,65,84,182,105,20,206,162,240,56,134,1,88,220,64,30,59,16,180,233,116,78,83,217,164,243,117,113,76,250,22,99,222,76,191,41,215,204,72,22,220,250,204,214,112,76,14,196,128,205,164,25,25,84,72,172,73,34,117,250,2,240,47,72,203,50,150,54,6,6,142,166,56,130,214,48,44,148,200,88,58,132,136,250,11,172,5,90,87,128,153,114,170,110,76,181,21,206,164,147,126,248,83,133,102,93,101,82,139,83,210,208,2,160,10,172,12,99,155,36,139,109,45,79,14,75,22,39,132,96,0,167,120,3,20,172,183,48,102,215,134,171,80,88,139,136,155,155,182,144,31,160,160,245,121,71,80,129,92,117,91,235,51,112,215,142,165,203,131,0,141,137,201,142,0,177,203,213,126,201,183,135,174,30,138,144,78,195,210,121,78,83,60,221,100,110,255,0,164,215,228,218,192,97,83,109,64,63,33,3,213,170,222,154,158,249,219,48,18,216,114,90,130,158,249,21,116,239,128,106,114,42,166,97,42,132,133,188,238,124,3,172,4,171,210,34,214,210,19,12,189,25,122,236,27,105,212,77,160,39,138,109,180,139,170,221,175,24,197,46,162,5,78,83,0,224,228,65,1,81,239,198,21,216,20,17,115,98,32,72,61,11,222,103,99,241,28,218,55,31,250,142,147,100,34,96,242,189,82,21,183,251,16,50,177,117,11,49,110,211,23,58,48,148,169,84,155,222,112,37,152,64,179,238,39,27,149,19,157,109,99,58,247,88,29,64,139,198,195,129,104,138,220,25,124,204,78,240,53,169,213,22,144,213,1,49,90,100,229,222,85,220,142,38,3,194,178,158,200,58,149,233,136,151,58,109,198,2,165,66,78,230,6,146,226,87,132,29,74,250,222,241,20,99,109,204,176,5,184,192,37,90,197,175,99,40,140,111,172,225,79,165,169,135,90,96,64,99,13,82,220,35,180,171,12,192,101,182,189,113,26,96,3,26,11,103,91,117,192,95,150,186,65,8,54,223,233,13,132,196,100,163,76,117,32,16,92,172,7,54,158,63,72,178,177,80,128,29,50,136,31,77,192,84,83,134,81,223,235,41,84,222,174,250,76,252,21,118,20,144,2,119,250,199,208,102,5,142,247,128,201,3,155,136,212,190,99,110,184,249,29,8,189,129,109,68,1,158,217,42,192,73,113,97,21,170,196,109,0,85,234,140,192,49,177,129,119,82,64,7,94,232,166,38,163,26,203,175,1,42,28,243,130,3,53,88,229,22,145,78,249,117,149,45,116,215,174,8,86,178,218,5,234,155,35,91,121,231,185,81,179,134,29,191,73,173,91,16,66,180,243,216,202,247,99,223,244,128,176,165,44,20,43,92,75,83,55,149,118,16,37,238,194,12,216,27,75,33,188,138,150,7,88,5,166,129,182,140,165,21,54,235,139,225,205,252,230,138,83,33,67,94,0,185,155,139,46,166,2,165,18,167,165,164,122,142,240,24,179,234,96,1,2,25,74,200,6,195,231,42,88,174,210,51,179,110,96,13,150,231,107,71,112,184,114,86,246,139,170,130,46,99,152,122,185,86,194,5,107,80,42,76,25,66,4,61,90,133,137,188,21,74,154,108,32,94,157,62,38,55,77,9,113,19,167,86,226,214,142,82,98,42,136,10,114,206,153,23,142,191,72,155,155,34,101,255,0,72,141,242,214,174,167,191,233,16,172,72,84,183,250,68,15,91,201,248,181,40,189,45,143,87,108,215,167,137,178,220,29,39,136,228,252,83,40,3,180,122,207,67,132,174,93,20,27,235,255,0,16,61,24,172,77,63,8,179,85,57,180,144,140,77,61,58,140,1,36,49,188,6,218,181,198,240,21,13,229,11,90,80,177,60,96,100,87,170,77,101,238,30,178,173,80,243,154,68,49,85,136,196,165,143,1,235,9,207,139,141,96,62,181,72,22,48,47,92,2,118,243,138,87,196,5,81,210,215,198,32,216,213,32,140,218,247,24,7,199,98,244,101,22,191,127,108,199,103,46,250,195,181,170,49,55,38,112,164,1,218,5,233,11,8,23,6,24,105,32,139,192,26,54,89,123,135,222,14,165,51,194,254,114,104,83,55,55,191,156,7,112,233,97,113,27,206,109,151,132,22,25,53,27,218,241,186,138,161,52,2,253,208,43,79,111,8,166,32,244,188,76,48,99,99,21,170,221,45,122,224,13,109,125,101,205,165,5,167,95,88,18,68,133,54,50,224,92,72,43,104,5,86,232,246,203,211,82,231,99,22,15,99,107,198,112,237,99,188,2,210,164,115,108,124,163,38,157,171,47,135,172,138,38,237,28,201,239,148,145,247,120,25,156,172,154,41,239,250,68,29,47,77,102,175,44,48,82,52,22,255,0,169,157,154,244,188,96,2,138,149,154,152,90,236,160,69,81,69,134,146,181,73,87,22,36,11,64,245,56,92,111,64,3,109,186,231,86,196,102,60,60,231,158,163,93,148,14,145,243,135,92,95,89,31,56,27,33,216,203,171,17,20,163,138,82,119,30,70,29,171,46,93,199,148,15,57,143,22,172,135,176,122,152,149,90,132,84,2,241,206,81,191,62,163,253,160,252,204,207,171,248,153,186,160,50,7,56,162,241,87,195,0,219,15,51,28,195,216,160,54,225,45,80,2,111,1,52,1,24,75,222,242,42,88,182,146,160,128,96,91,89,122,99,89,201,99,36,181,142,208,14,170,8,151,90,96,54,163,132,174,28,134,227,25,25,84,107,99,225,2,188,226,33,148,169,137,92,214,4,223,194,14,187,41,109,45,23,81,122,160,219,72,14,37,64,221,113,106,203,118,241,49,133,1,86,226,47,90,228,233,2,128,72,183,74,29,83,54,198,88,208,97,172,1,45,196,147,114,33,66,229,93,96,90,165,143,195,0,69,14,109,161,233,130,164,94,117,54,25,129,34,24,140,228,88,64,115,10,46,1,236,17,240,192,216,246,218,35,135,66,7,128,140,174,150,94,179,123,192,87,150,146,244,21,187,253,68,201,172,165,41,167,104,6,108,114,191,254,186,47,126,190,34,101,98,216,10,52,248,232,4,14,166,250,9,213,143,76,30,201,68,0,145,175,24,87,0,157,246,211,104,28,166,226,69,141,225,85,64,27,252,165,136,10,47,188,1,38,100,55,151,53,216,13,254,82,181,27,162,76,91,61,218,3,124,165,255,0,176,191,225,245,51,58,179,106,102,159,41,33,53,214,195,251,126,166,102,215,166,193,142,144,13,65,237,76,73,168,218,65,83,54,80,37,137,184,210,0,25,236,210,134,230,17,147,165,34,214,225,2,212,219,44,135,108,219,73,2,251,200,0,110,32,18,139,20,214,77,92,69,200,176,156,171,153,116,148,42,51,17,3,169,177,102,218,104,81,165,117,6,45,68,34,157,72,242,143,37,69,10,53,128,50,182,6,40,206,3,219,182,56,29,72,55,60,38,125,95,197,39,133,204,7,176,170,21,181,35,206,56,236,133,62,33,231,50,17,201,59,152,96,88,255,0,113,128,106,170,9,208,143,56,179,211,215,113,9,149,143,19,40,200,215,222,4,42,118,136,222,21,192,97,120,162,171,6,222,19,13,124,250,192,216,165,80,19,97,44,126,53,239,137,225,216,115,155,198,143,198,176,20,229,167,181,53,241,250,76,124,99,94,130,120,122,77,94,91,252,53,241,250,76,156,78,180,80,14,207,72,18,151,186,233,198,89,137,204,116,151,164,46,20,240,156,234,115,24,12,83,189,132,181,79,134,66,104,5,231,87,7,36,5,139,93,12,94,231,49,134,91,101,50,185,117,48,61,14,58,133,235,166,188,7,172,207,199,97,200,60,102,190,51,74,233,220,61,98,56,231,23,16,49,222,153,88,37,107,27,70,171,48,49,51,241,105,0,198,197,101,109,57,47,112,37,136,129,77,167,91,73,198,85,78,176,46,9,81,40,21,139,146,7,202,89,216,2,33,105,30,142,130,5,0,124,219,124,163,0,176,22,34,7,157,33,182,156,248,131,123,90,1,212,233,4,84,23,151,162,217,135,132,171,11,52,9,100,28,13,228,42,53,228,93,151,121,34,180,11,101,107,194,135,0,107,0,106,153,91,147,0,175,80,112,149,160,221,41,83,96,59,100,80,61,40,14,80,62,242,104,143,141,123,230,118,30,220,228,125,94,245,23,190,2,220,182,164,210,79,31,164,200,174,45,77,59,132,216,229,150,247,75,227,244,153,56,159,195,78,225,0,212,127,13,100,190,142,59,164,81,252,53,157,87,127,8,7,67,121,21,155,163,105,212,77,199,132,13,86,57,173,218,96,83,251,76,234,106,204,77,132,45,58,68,131,26,195,80,28,96,107,99,117,174,157,195,214,33,142,77,68,209,198,11,87,78,225,235,16,199,147,113,111,189,160,101,215,91,24,145,54,105,164,87,48,55,235,137,86,80,26,5,80,234,33,109,7,79,112,97,134,208,4,208,57,181,140,48,129,101,179,8,20,168,221,33,13,73,142,93,204,27,160,176,157,240,232,32,92,124,82,92,2,118,16,42,78,120,86,38,240,28,164,160,46,146,149,4,154,68,229,148,168,76,8,212,238,73,144,64,234,144,9,156,111,2,116,234,145,121,40,183,18,230,156,1,222,86,155,89,165,217,45,6,136,75,113,242,128,221,6,233,113,143,169,233,9,155,73,72,110,51,65,62,33,223,0,92,172,222,233,124,126,147,47,17,173,4,240,244,154,124,172,61,210,248,253,38,94,39,74,41,225,233,1,154,58,101,239,147,83,86,50,139,123,175,124,150,6,228,246,192,45,51,97,225,7,151,51,202,2,97,112,227,167,1,202,10,183,141,170,168,216,90,14,154,40,48,192,8,14,227,173,207,47,112,136,98,133,219,104,238,56,48,170,186,29,135,8,165,82,217,190,19,1,26,130,222,115,54,184,37,181,154,245,85,136,189,142,253,83,42,186,156,199,127,40,11,169,32,219,132,50,188,1,82,91,140,144,134,3,57,129,130,123,22,18,161,100,133,233,136,18,195,65,42,71,24,87,22,81,41,107,192,173,53,4,222,21,148,25,200,182,134,11,113,2,244,212,5,131,168,53,135,65,164,21,97,104,3,80,37,172,39,90,210,12,11,211,3,88,91,11,64,38,130,92,190,144,33,172,90,69,34,3,108,37,25,181,147,78,228,192,101,114,222,52,131,164,59,226,116,150,237,31,79,136,119,192,91,149,71,186,95,31,164,204,196,11,210,75,246,77,94,86,252,37,241,250,76,188,79,225,39,132,6,20,2,202,59,101,170,0,46,4,26,158,146,247,206,172,214,188,14,181,141,128,134,195,47,189,2,10,131,102,113,28,195,143,126,7,124,7,145,59,33,22,152,60,37,65,33,132,54,107,90,3,60,167,84,115,168,44,54,28,59,226,129,193,125,64,242,140,242,157,18,43,37,237,176,245,49,54,33,28,94,4,226,50,128,13,135,148,199,196,45,201,32,77,151,117,100,17,58,212,193,83,97,192,192,196,114,3,25,0,222,26,181,30,147,24,27,90,5,167,39,198,47,43,44,8,12,53,128,119,203,151,88,49,107,202,213,97,97,172,133,213,111,0,135,178,21,52,26,197,193,191,24,85,225,1,148,16,88,146,45,46,173,164,5,99,120,1,44,100,169,36,200,201,11,77,32,64,188,226,27,170,50,136,45,194,89,128,2,2,96,27,235,12,160,40,131,170,64,188,174,125,45,1,138,12,115,246,71,81,134,97,223,51,232,29,99,172,111,150,221,112,7,202,236,5,21,36,233,175,210,102,87,96,105,39,132,119,150,21,191,166,67,223,234,38,94,38,252,197,59,117,15,72,14,139,230,94,249,103,166,238,77,133,199,124,166,20,230,168,128,255,0,168,122,207,85,130,194,35,81,6,195,204,245,64,243,88,74,108,42,139,136,254,23,40,197,11,245,153,173,83,1,149,137,10,60,204,68,167,53,136,185,22,212,192,150,127,120,45,58,171,49,181,164,173,137,150,117,184,210,3,252,165,80,154,201,190,195,143,105,136,87,213,196,111,148,129,21,211,184,122,152,173,86,212,13,32,84,88,44,13,99,209,54,234,48,202,108,53,235,148,36,19,188,12,215,166,88,24,149,68,33,167,160,52,193,93,226,21,40,244,137,188,12,183,66,4,161,13,152,111,30,196,45,150,35,112,43,41,23,251,48,57,213,140,176,186,165,143,92,100,97,170,98,5,209,78,157,134,39,86,141,74,85,10,184,177,238,129,106,36,147,25,23,26,197,168,146,91,134,226,52,87,164,47,0,200,46,32,235,11,66,81,22,242,131,173,169,241,128,45,68,169,168,87,175,206,78,144,85,65,59,64,98,141,98,84,239,191,92,43,61,196,70,150,100,6,227,140,33,168,109,180,11,84,59,193,169,214,210,133,250,83,144,221,196,7,169,8,210,116,89,111,214,34,180,245,17,128,58,75,110,184,19,203,76,63,162,79,31,81,50,42,48,254,157,123,199,164,211,229,170,103,250,52,35,183,212,76,154,136,199,12,151,7,113,233,1,186,58,84,66,58,196,245,28,155,88,228,85,185,243,236,158,78,133,150,162,94,251,137,233,249,54,170,89,69,245,253,160,111,85,3,44,199,199,208,36,220,117,153,181,68,7,81,99,45,91,10,74,105,3,202,41,176,38,18,149,75,222,55,139,194,149,91,235,18,90,121,79,24,26,188,161,73,154,178,119,15,83,17,175,69,185,193,172,250,13,127,99,42,57,14,107,173,199,251,207,233,137,86,246,58,169,127,198,79,206,127,76,15,26,180,58,58,239,6,248,114,14,147,219,175,177,213,109,248,203,249,207,233,149,111,100,170,143,254,180,255,0,49,253,48,60,57,71,26,65,181,7,51,220,255,0,226,21,111,248,180,255,0,49,253,50,199,217,26,182,252,74,95,152,254,152,31,56,196,208,107,69,41,225,149,177,8,160,111,111,89,244,138,254,198,59,111,85,63,55,241,128,161,236,83,127,84,141,206,165,197,191,187,183,252,96,100,114,79,39,42,225,201,63,122,158,217,141,203,88,64,184,179,111,189,76,250,125,47,101,107,45,44,162,173,48,59,24,255,0,196,196,229,79,99,107,213,196,19,207,167,87,198,122,207,251,96,124,218,134,29,185,205,15,17,28,169,135,96,39,174,161,236,69,101,127,199,77,199,247,159,211,25,173,236,125,84,25,154,178,16,58,152,254,152,30,62,134,21,136,240,131,169,135,179,235,214,103,182,165,236,243,1,96,233,231,251,72,111,100,217,205,197,85,28,126,47,227,3,192,62,28,168,130,200,215,181,167,208,143,177,142,202,111,85,63,55,241,149,167,236,81,45,173,84,252,223,198,7,129,230,216,240,249,202,182,26,161,216,79,163,167,177,4,255,0,244,79,205,252,97,151,216,147,111,142,159,159,241,129,242,239,233,170,223,111,73,117,195,56,55,180,250,115,123,19,166,175,79,207,248,193,55,177,128,15,196,79,205,252,96,120,10,52,222,104,225,176,110,196,119,207,89,67,216,243,158,220,226,126,111,227,52,71,178,252,194,130,29,78,188,79,237,3,231,220,185,66,162,97,208,91,77,125,68,206,174,150,195,83,25,117,208,239,217,62,147,202,190,206,115,248,100,204,80,111,177,237,29,147,58,175,178,65,169,160,46,187,14,63,198,7,134,230,9,117,32,113,154,120,48,202,194,223,122,79,103,79,216,165,117,86,231,22,255,0,229,252,99,20,253,140,40,227,222,173,183,248,191,140,12,238,79,14,217,111,247,172,215,52,142,65,221,53,176,94,204,50,101,181,68,243,237,238,154,141,236,235,228,29,52,243,253,160,120,12,78,16,186,218,34,220,156,111,247,255,0,51,232,95,248,203,54,245,23,243,126,210,31,217,66,71,226,47,230,253,160,127,255,217]
```

I tried this to get json obj of the image from the link:

byte[] imagefile=jsonObject.getString("IMGFILE1").getBytes();

and put this code to read it but imageview represents null from the below code:

> try {
>                  imagefile=Base64.decode(image_file,Base64.DEFAULT);

```
      } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
       }

          Bitmap bitmap = new BitmapFactory().decodeByteArray(imagefile, 0/* starting index*/, imagefile.length/*no of byte to read*/);

        imgPern.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
         imgPern.setImageBitmap(
                BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imagefile, 0, imagefile.length)
                 );
```

Suggestions are most welcome...!! Thank You

Comment: "IMGFILE1" values is not a String is a JSONArray...

Comment: so instead of jsonObject.getString("IMGFILE1")..use jsonObject.getJSONArray("IMGFILE1") and then try to convert the decimal to bytearray and so

Comment: Mr.Downvoter Could You Plz explain the reason for downvoting..!!??!! And I update the Answer as well

Answer (score 1):

) Very nice image !)
Try this :

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

As you see, your response is a byte array , so must decode it. First try to handle it and than decode into bitmap. Good luck

Comment: Sorry but this is only half an answer,. Or a third. Or less. You should start showing how to set up `byteArray` and filling it with the values from the json text.

Comment: What about all the numbers above 128?

Comment: You should put them in too!

Comment: @greenapps but how do you get them into the byte array! :)

Comment: Guys updated the question with the code I had already tried..!!

Comment: `but how do you get them into the byte array! :`. Just like the others. Why are you suddenly using base64 decode? Who told you that it is base64 encoded? And have you checked what `jsonObject.getString("IMGFILE1")` delivers? Log it, print it so you know. And did you listen to Angad Tiwari and used `jsonObject.getJSONArray("IMGFILE1") ` ? Print and log it to see if it delivers what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer For My Question...

> image_file=jsonObject.getString("IMGFILE1");

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<byte[]>(){}.getType();

    byte[] parsed = gson.fromJson(image_file, collectionType);

    bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(parsed, 0, parsed.length);
```

I was able to do that by downloading the GSON library to execute this issue...